# cordova remote android android app - load all other links in web browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

So my app should be pretty simple, here is the scope:

1. The entire app is a remote website.
2. First page is the login on the remote server.
3. After login just redirect to the remote home page, as the web page does automatically from a browser (but stay in the app).
4. All links that reside within the main domain stay in app.
5. All link from another domain open web browser.
6. Cookies need to be enabled to stay logged in.
7. I don't need to access any device API, everything is in the online website

I have read several article on how to achieve this with Cordova, but my problem is - the first page loads from the server as desired, but after I login, the app opens the home page in a web browser.

Here is my Cordova config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myremoteapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Remote Web App</name>
    <description>
Remote Web App description
    </description>
    <author email="contact@example.com" href="https://example.com">
    WebappAuthor
    </author>
    <content src="https://example.com/login" />
    <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true"/> 
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <!--   <content src="index.html" />   -->
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Note: I just edited these lines, to replace the default local index.html:

```
    <content src="https://example.com/login" />
    <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <!--   <content src="index.html" />   -->
```

Thanks, any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: it seems I have to use webview in android, so kinda pointless to use cordova for remote apps